# Tax Calculation and Tax Display issues

Tags: magento2

I would like to set all the products to show prices with tax included for
logged in users as well as guest users, but besides I tried all possible
combinations with tax settings, I didn't managed to set this up,
as I've encounter all sorts of weird behaviors. In addition,
it seems there is separate issue with "Catalog New Product List" widget
in that regard. Please read the explanation bellow.

Global settings:

- Magento version 2.4.1
- Shipping origin is set to Serbia.
- Product price is set to 100 din.
- Tax rate is set to 20%.

At "Tax settings" in admin panel, only change is:

- Stores > Configuration > Sales > Tax > Default Tax Destination Calculation > Default Country > Serbia

**What is happening:**

"Catalog New Product List" widget shows the product price of 100 din.
for guest user which is fine, but when I logged in with the registered user,
at first, the price is still hanging at 100 din, but after I refresh the page
the price changes to 83.33 din. which is amount with deducted tax percentage,
which is wrong.

When I click the same product and go to product page, the price
displayed is 100 din. which is the correct one.

When I click "View and Edit Cart" and go to `../checkout/cart` page,
the cart summary for logged in user is calculated as 100 din. + 20 din. (tax amount)
equal 120 din. in total and that's OK, but with the guest user, cart summary is
calculated as 100 din. + 0 for tax amount which is wrong. So, I ended up
with one product price for guest user, another totally wrong calculated price
at "Catalog New Product List" widget for logged in user, then one total amount
of 100 din. for guest user and different total amount of 120 din. for logged in user.

Basically, I can't set up the correct prices with tax amount for guest user, as
Magento keep deducting tax amount for guest user instead of adding it to price
value. I've managed to set up what I want, but just for logged in user.
For guest user I always end up with prices without tax amount (83.33 din)
instead of 120 din. which will be the right one. On top of that there is that widget
price odd behavior.

I can't figure it out what is wrong here and how to handle it, but it seems to me
that something is really not right...

Any help will be highly appreciated.

### Question Update

**Tax Zone and Rates**

[image]

**Stores > Configuration > Sales > Tax (settings #1)**

[image]

**Results for logged in user:**

[image]

**Results for guest user:**

[image]

**Stores > Configuration > Sales > Tax (settings #2)**

[image]

**Results for logged in user:**

[image]

**Results for guest user:**

[image]

Comment: Do you only ship to Serbia? If so, go to Configuration > General > Allowe Countries and deselect all except Serbia and select Default Country as Serbia. Then review your Tax Calculation settings in Configuration > Sales > Tax. In particular, review whether you have Including Tax or Excluding Tax for display and input prices. Suspect they may not be aligned. And make sure your Tax Rate in Stores > Tax Zones and Rates is set to Country Serbia. If you still have problems, update the question with a screenshot of your tax page settings so we can see.

Comment: @bernieu2, thank you very much for the answer.
I changed the allowed countries to Serbia only and there is some progress as well,
but unfortunately, it's far away from what should be expected. 

"Catalog New Product List" widget now shows price as expected, and that's great,
but price display is still different for logged in user in comparison
with guest user. Also, Magento keep deducting the tax amount instead
of adding it to the product price. Please take a look at question update
for more info and screenshots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, you want to enter prices in product admin **Excluding Tax** e.g $100 - and then display all prices in frontend **Including Tax** - e.g. $120.

If so, you should set "Catalog Prices" to Excluding Tax. All other settings should be changed to Including Tax. Magento will automatically add tax on if product is set as Taxable Goods.

Please try these settings:

[image: calculation settings]

[image: display settings]

Make sure that you have set **Shipping Origin country** and it is the same country as set in Tax > **Default Tax Destination Calculation**. If they are not aligned, prices will be displayed excluding tax for guest users.

As per Docs:

> The point of origin is used to calculate the charge for shipments made from your store or warehouse, and also determines the tax rate for products sold. When calculating EU taxes, make sure that the Default Tax Destination Calculation for each store view corresponds to the Shipping Settings point of origin.

https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/shipping/point-of-origin.html

Comment: Yes, you understand it right. I slightly changed the settings and I've excluded tax for "Shipping", because it's free of charge (no value). Also, for "Display Subtotal" I've put "Including and Excluding Tax". Anyway, this works perfectly with logged in (registered) user only. Exactly what I've expected :). Unfortunately, for quest user, nothing has happened at all. Price is displayed as 100 din. instead of 120 din. Tax amount isn't calculated at all. So, the only issue left now, is how to display the prices for guest (unregistered) user as well as for logged in (registered) user.

Comment: Possibly you need to set Shipping Origin country? https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/configuration/sales/shipping-settings.html

Comment: I already realized that. "Shipping Origin" was set to Serbia from the beginning. It's stated at the beginning of the question, under the "Global settings:". "Tax Calculation" should be based on "Shipping Origin" as well, so that Magento should know what tax to include to guest users, right. Anyway, it's a bit weird, since there is no price change for quest user although it seems that everything is setup correctly.

Comment: Ok, strange, it looks like you are using single store mode so no scope switching could affect it seems. Only other place I could think to check is Customers > Customer Groups and check Tax Class is same for both Not Logged In (0) and General (1) groups. But is the guest user getting charged any tax at anytime to complete checkout?

Comment: Tax Class for "NOT LOGGED IN" user in `Customers > Customer Groups` was messed up for some reason. I fixed that up and everything is in perfect order now. Almost, I don't believe that is working after all :). WELL DONE MATE. THANK YOU VERY VERY MUCH for your help and I wish you all the best.